# How to use .sub on a variable in rails

Tags: select, ruby-on-rails-4, substring

I am trying to strip the parent directory path out of my string variable for display.

Here is my command that generates the list of directories for my select_tag to display:

```
<% @get_dir_list = Dir["/watchfolder/miniprod/*"].sort %>
```

Here is what it currently displays:
    /watchfolder/hot
    /watchfolder/inhouse
    /watchfolder/contract/inhouse

Here is what I want to display:
   /hot
   /inhouse
   /contract/inhouse

I want to strip the parent path off of the display list of sub-directories to make it easier for the user to read.

Here is the command that I have.   I can't seem to get the formatting correct:

```
<% @get_dir_list_display = @get_dir_list.sub(/[watchfolder]/,'') %>
```

In addition,  How do I use sub for this string:   "watchfolder/archive"   I'm not sure how to setup the sub with the '/' (slash) included.

```
<% @get_dir_list_display = @get_dir_list.sub(/[watchfolder/archive]/,'') %>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Answer #1 solves my problem; however,  How can I get it to work for this case: "watchfolder/archive"?    Because of the '/' slash in my text string, it is throwing the formatting for substring off.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to map:

`@get_dir_list.map{ |dir| dir.sub(/\/watchfolder/, '') }`